# Div on top of ViewRight-player

Tags: html, css, flash

http://clubace.dk/viewright_test.htm

The green `div` at the bottom of the page is overlapped by the player as soon as the player loads.

I've tried setting wmode to 'transparent' in both the object tag and the `param` tag, but that doesn't help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeChannel(url, chanid)
  {
  var player = document.getElementById('ViewRightControl');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  if (video != null)
  {
    video.src = url;
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }
  else if (player != null)
  {
    player.Close();
    player.Open(url, false);
  }
    if(chanid != 0)
    {
      update(chanid);
    }
    else
    {
      tvclear();
    }

}

function update(channelid) {
  $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
  console.log(data[channelid][0]);

  $('.now').html("<strong>" + data[channelid][0]['title'] + "</strong><br>" + data[channelid][0]['starttime'] + "<br>");


  $('.next').html("<strong>" + data[channelid][1]['title'] + "</strong><br>" + data[channelid][1]['starttime'] + "<br>");
});

}

function tvclear() {
  $('.now').html("No data");
  $('.next').html("No data");
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: black;
    cursor: auto;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
:::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
#ViewRightControl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#selectorHolder {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>

</head>
<body onload="changeChannel('http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8', 0);">
<object id="ViewRightControl" type="application/x-viewright-m3u8" wmode="transparent">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
<div id="selectorHolder">

</div>
</body></html>
```

I'm using this ViewRight plugin from Verimatrix (for Windows):
http://warehouse.yousee.tv.s3.amazonaws.com/misc/plugin/YouSee.msi

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Sure thing :)
If you're using Chrome just Ctrl+U on the page or use this url
view-source:http://clubace.dk/viewright_test.htm

Comment: what is the 'z-index: 100;' in the #selectorholder for?

Comment: It was my initial attempt to place the div above the object-tag.

Comment: Its fine I was just wondering thats all, this is quite a weird problem I must say :S

Comment: That's okay :)
Yeah I've never encountered this behavior before when embedding flash players :S
The wmode="transparent" usually takes care of business so I'm pretty stumped by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!!

It's a NPAPI plugin and here's a way to put something on top of that: [HTML on top of NPAPI plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372162/html-on-top-of-npapi-plugin)

Comment: By the way, I hope VeriMatrix are working on an alternative to their NPAPI plugin since it's deprecated and will be gone by the end of this year: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/05/update-on-npapi-deprecation.html

Comment: Well done @Jan Sommer :D This is a simple and clever workaround :thumbsup: Thanks